# Backend view of data from custom database

Tags: database, adminhtml, backend, magento-1

I have made a custom database, that stores the data from a form. 
Now i want the data to be displayed backend.

What is the best way to do this? 
If you need to se my code just say so :)

Comment: create module to display data in backend. use module creator if you are new in magento module.

Comment: I have made a module that create the database. but i dont know how to display it :P

Comment: just read and follow these 
http://inchoo.net/magento/getting-started-with-building-admin-module-in-magento/

http://inchoo.net/magento/how-to-create-a-custom-grid-from-scratch/